# Javascript upload files to page, without going over a WebServer

Tags: javascript, file-io

I'm wondering if it is possible, to upload a file from the local Computer to a page, without uploading it to a webserver first and then download it from there with ajax.

Can this work with just Javascript & Google Chrome, or must I use flash or something like that?

Comment: What do you want to do with the file? Is this for personal use?

Comment: whatever for. I don't want to access the files manually from the appliction. I want to get the contents of a file, which the user as dragged on it.

Comment: This makes sense if the javascript can process or preprocess the uploaded file locally.  For example, to verify it's valid, strip out unneeded information, etc - all without potentially long and bandwidth hungry uploads to wait for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must go to the server first. I suppose it might be possible to do a temporary upload to a page but for anything permanent you would need to use a webserver and server side code. All of this can be done in javascript (but would recommend jQuery to make your life easier) and a server side scripting language such as PHP or ASP.